# How can i add a url to my cover_image on rails 4 using carrierware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

To be specific, Let's say i have model called Products and it has a column called :cover_image which holds the picture

I have mounted the uploader and everything works fine

Except that for now i want to add a custom url to a new product or existing one

for example

I want to do like this

```
p = Product.last
p.cover_image = "something"
```

it didn't work

I added

```
attr_accessor :cover_image_url
```

and now i'm able to do

```
p.cover_image_url = "something"
```

once i do

```
p.save
```

it acts like everything went fine

except the cover_image column still empty

how can i populate it with a link manually ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please expand on what "it didn't work" means.

Comment: Sorry for being less descriptive,
I mean it passed, and gave no errors
Except when you check Product.find(this_product).cover_image
it's nil still

Answer (score 0):

If you need a custom url for some Products and others you are happy with the uploaded image url, here's what I would do. (I recommend leaving the `cover_image_url` as it is and create a separate column for custom url)

1 - Create a separate column called `custom_url` (leave the `cover_image_url`)

2 - remove `attr_accessor :cover_image_url` and leave it as it was (because it overrides the up loader functionality)

3 - Update the product model to have a method to return url

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ... other code   

  def image_url
    # return custom_url if it has one, or the standard url
    # you can change this logic as you want
    custom_url || cover_image_url
  end
end
```

4 - Now, instead of calling  `p.cover_image_url` I'll call `p.image_url`

```
p = Product.last
p.image_url
```

Comment: I already did that before even posing as a temporary solution,
Actually i wanted to apply this to :cover_image to keep everything in one place,
So until a better solution comes, i'll stick with my current way which is same as your

Thanks btw for your effort :)